# Associating a custom contex menu to a ContextList widget

Tags: dojo, ibm-content-navigator

Is there any way to associate a custom contextMenu to a contentList widget(the widget used to display search results)?

Comment: Are you asking specifically for the search "Feature" within ICN or are you asking about adding it to a conentList in general?

Answer (score 1):

IBM Content Navigator uses `RowContextMenu` as the JavaScript that is used on a Contentlist.

`ecm.widget.listView.gridModules.RowContextMenu
@class This module displays the context menu when the user right clicks or hits Shift F10. It also provides default action capability.`

You can extend this class, creating a custom menu.
Then define it within your custom class :
`define(["dojo/_base/declare", ..., "myPlugin/myCustomRowContextMenu",...], 
function(declare...,RowContextMenu,...) {
return declare("myPlugin.myCustomPane", [
        ContentPane]...`

Then use it :
`_getContentListGridExtensionModules: function() {
            var modules = [];
            modules.push(RowContextMenu);
            return modules;
        },`